# selected item of dropDownSelectTree disappeared when create button in TabbedForm(React admin) change

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am working with react admin and I am using TabbedForm to add data, the problem is that when I select item from dropDownSelectTree, and then add text to TextInput, the create button change from disable to able and my selected itemed disappeared, I want to know how to keep my selected items when the button change.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things from incorrect state handling to incorrect props setup. However, without the actual code to check not many people will be able to help you out. So if you may, share your code with us.